# The usage of 'as in' in a sentence starting with 'nor'

Tags: meaning

The Elantra Sport is a fun car to drive, even if there isn’t nearly as much front-end grip as the newest Civic Si, nor does aggressive trail-braking net any oversteer in tight turns as in the Ford Focus ST.

---

Does this sentence mean that the Ford Focus ST nets some oversteer in tight turns when this car does aggressive trail-braking?

Due to the presence of 'as in' in the sentence above, I finds it somewhat vague...

And does the writer view that character of the Ford Focus as something positive?

Comment: First and foremost that sentence shows the the author is more concerned with his own immediate thoughts than with any rules of language.
The “as in” you mention is one of the smallest doubts!
If that passage could be said to show the writer viewed that character of the Ford Focus as something positive, it would be difficult, at best.
In any case where is your own research, please?

Comment: Most likely the writer does view the ability to induce oversteer as a positive trait - drivers will use that characteristic to help the car turn. You really can't get this out of the passage quoted, though - I'm making an assumption from prior knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> The Elantra Sport is a fun car to drive, even if there isn’t nearly as much front-end grip as the newest Civic Si, nor does aggressive trail-braking net any oversteer in tight turns as in the Ford Focus ST.

I suspect your difficulty with the long *even if* clause may have something to do with how this conjunction is used and perhaps with another meaning of *as in* with which you might be confusing this particular usage.

#### *Even if…*

*Even if* introduces a concessive clause despite which a statement is still true. It may be used for unreal conditions:

> As I drank to quench my unquenchable thirst, I thought to myself, “[*Even if*](http://diabetesdailypost.com/positive-outlook-leads-to-a-positive-outcome/) I drank the ocean, I would still be thirsty!”

With real conditions, *even if* is equivalent to *even though* or *although*:

> [*Even if*](https://books.google.de/books?id=YwS85VcFziAC&pg=PA356&dq=%22even+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8xfzKgbLaAhXKa1AKHcfKAdg4FBDoAQhMMAc) you're between jobs, stay active and open-minded; even if you've landed your dream job, maintain outside interests.
>
> You do not have to buy your child sugar-coated cereals if you don't want to, [*even if*](https://books.google.de/books?id=uFg9BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA482&dq=%22even+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrmu21grLaAhXFaVAKHal7DU84MhDoAQhMMAc) he has seen them on his favorite television program and puts pressure on you to buy them.

In your sentence, the Electra Sport is still a fun car to drive, even if one concedes that the Si and Focus ST both have attractive features the Sport either has less of or lacks entirely. And yes, the author implies that front-end grip and oversteer in tight turns are desirable features.

#### *As in…*

*As in* as a single unit means ‘in the sense of’. It’s often used to talk about the meaning or pronunciation of words:

[image]

[image]

In your sentence, however, *as* and *in* keep their separate meanings: the preposition *in* is incidental:

> In Germany [*as*](http://www.mitchellake.com/news/2016/3/22/eurotrip-slash-slash-a-journey-through-europes-startup-scene-germany) in most countries, there is a big lack of skilled developers.
>
> In Germany— [*as*](http://www.scifijapan.com/articles/2009/06/05/gualagon-japanese-monster-german-style/) with most countries— the Japanese kaiju/science fiction boom kicked off with the release of Toho's GODZILLA, which opened in theaters there in August 1956...

In your sentence, *as the newest Civic Si* and *as in the Ford Focus ST* are in parallel, giving specific examples of the features described more generally.  The preposition *in* could have just as easily appeared with the Civic. In fact, the meaning would have been clearer had the writer done so.

Comment: WOW!!! What a perfect, unquestionable, and unequivocal  answer!!!       I can't be more thankful!